# order objects with encrypted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I'm using attr_encryptor gem for encryption.
I wonder if it is possible to order my objects with encrypted data like :

```
@origins = Origin.order('name ASC').all
```

Of course it is not good, because name values are encrypted.
Is it possible by another way ? I tried with :

```
@origins.sort! { |a,b| a.name <=> b.name }
```

But it doesn't works...
Any idea ?

Comment: Try with @origins.sort_by(&:name)

Comment: Since the gem decrypts it for you when you load it from db, you can get it working by doing @origins.sort_by(&:name)